# Android Broadcast receiver not getting called after force close

Tags: android, alarm

So this is a weird one.

My app needs to notify the user on a regular basis. Once every week more or less. Looking at the various different options, WorkManager, AlarmManager, there doesnt seem to be an option for doing what I want which seems crazy... If I swipe the app from recents the alarm fires but the broadcast receiver doesn't, unless I add alarm to the applicationId in the build file. Does that mean that android checks the app id and if it contains alarm it lets it call the receiver? I am using a one plus 3 device with android 9. Not sure if this is device specific.

To test this just run https://github.com/nikit19/AlarmManager and change the appid to something without alarm to see it doesnt work. Run the app, select a time for the alarm and force close the app. If the appid has alarm, the alarm will call the receiver and a notification will show. If not, nothing will happen.

Is there a way to do what I want? Is the only way push notifications?